# Asterisk 11.* TLS Configuration

Tags: centos, asterisk, sip

I have [installed](http://blogs.digium.com/2012/11/05/how-to-install-asterisk-11-on-centos-6/) asterisk 11.12.0 on CentOS (64-bit). When enabling the `TLS` support i get the following error

WARNING[7620]: tcptls.c:673 handle_tcptls_connection: FILE * open failed!

i tried disabling the `TLS` option on the server but still get this error. Also when i generate the certificates i get a

```
comman name does not match
```

error.

On the `CLI` i can see a `SSL Certificate OK` message.

What could be the reason for this behavior and how can it be resolved.

sip.conf

```
[general]
context=local
allowguest=no
alwaysauthreject=yes
allow=ulaw
allow=alaw
allow=gsm
directmedia=yes  

allowoverlap=no
bindport=5061
tlsdontverifyserver=yes      
tlsenable=yes
tlsbindaddr=192.168.0.119
tlscertfile=/etc/asterisk/keys/asterisk.pem
tlscafile=/etc/asterisk/keys/ca.crt
tlscapath=/etc/asterisk/keys
register => tls://john:password@192.168.0.119:5061
register => tls://jane:password@192.168.0.119:5061
tlscipher=ALL
tlsclientmethod=tlsv1
localnet=192.168.0.119/255.255.255.0

[john]
type=peer
defaultuser=john
secret=password
dtmfmode=rfc2833
callerid="User one"
host=dynamic      
canreinvite=no
nat=no
encryption=yes
transport=tls

[jane]
type=peer
defaultuser=jane
secret=password
dtmfmode=rfc2833
callerid="User two"
host=dynamic   
canreinvite=no
nat=no
encryption=yes
transport=tls
```

Regards.

Comment: Edit your question and add the relevant configuration files.

Comment: @AndréDaniel i have edited the question plz have a look

Comment: What are you trying to do ? Register to a remote SIP server using TLS or allow clients to register on your server using TLS ?

Comment: allow clients to register to my server using TLS

Comment: common name issue has been resolved, i followed https://wiki.asterisk.org/wiki/display/AST/Secure+Calling+Tutorial when i do `sip reload` i can see SSL Certificate OK

Comment: Okay, well then look [here](https://wiki.asterisk.org/wiki/display/AST/SIP+TLS+Transport) in the "server_b" configuration.

Comment: i have also included the user conf in the question edit, plz have a look, the only diff i can spot from link u provided it the `type=peer`